# Test for function or content word? (LFG)

Tags: syntax, english, copula, lfg

This might only apply to LFG, but are there any tests for if a word is functional or content/lexical?

I have been trying to ascertain whether or not there is a lexical 'be' in English. The active 'be' in sentences like 'don't be silly' may only be adding an 'active' feature to the content word, similar to morpheme -ing. It seems to be a copula, though maybe a lexical copula like 'act' - 'don't act silly'.

Comment: In LFG, content words have a PRED attribute. Copulae are taken to be function words in modern LFG because they have no PRED. In "don't be silly" the adjective is the only predicator.

Comment: Does that mean copulae in sentences like 'you seem cold' also have no PRED attribute? I was thinking that since only a handful of lexical copulae exist it might be possible to assign their meanings as functional attributes.

Is there any way of actually testing whether a word has a PRED attribute?

Comment: How semi-copulae (pseudo-copulae) are analysed depends on the underlying theory. Some regard them as complex predicates (Alsina, Manning). On this view, they indeed have a PRED attribute but it's generic and needs to be unified with that of the main verb. In the end, it's language specific, but they definitely have a PRED. In general, whether a word has a PRED attribute depends on its semantics, there's no general rule for deciding that.